# Is it possible to measure the number of users (as compared to contributors) of a BitBucket repo with the API?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I have created a BitBucket repo for my team of commonly used functions and want to measure adoption over time. I do not expect many people to contribute to the repo, but all measurements seem to be focused on commits and pull requests.

Is it possible to tell how many people and how often people are pulling the repo to ensure it’s up to date (the habit we are trying to encourage).

Comment: Hey, please specify if you are using Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server platform. The possibilities might be quite different between those two platforms.